# Can we determine if $A$ is invertible from this?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, can we determine whether $A$ is invertible given that:

$A^3 - 3A^2 + 2A - I = 0$

We can turn this matrix equation into:

$A^3 - 3A^2 + 2A = I $

$A(A^2-3A+2I)=I$

So, $A$ has the inverse $A^2-3A+2I$. Is this the true way to solve the problem? I hope I was correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: yes but you have to think about why, there is a deeper reason. In particular you dont have to do any more work here because A is a square matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is absolutely correct and the most elementary way. Here is some extra information to justify leaving this as an answer ($A$ will denote an $n \times n$ matrix throughout):

$A$ is invertible iff $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

$A$ satisfies many polynomial equations. There is a monic polynomial of least degree that it satisfies, called the *minimal polynomial*. The minimal polynomial has the following properties:

- It divides every polynomial that $A$ divides.
- Every eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of the minimal polynomial (and thus, a root of every polynomial that $A$ divides).

In your example, $A$ satisfies the polynomial $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 1$. Since $0$ is not a root of this polynomial (the constant coefficient is nonzero), it follows that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Thus, $A$ is invertible.